# Can't get footer to not show up when I scroll up the page

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am designing a footer for my website. The footer is currently stuck to the bottom but it always shows up in the viewport, whether I'm at the top of the page, middle, or bottom.

**Desired Result:** The footer should stay at the bottom of the page and *not appear* in the viewport unless the bottom of page is actually inside the viewport

**Actual Result:** The footer shows up in the viewport regardless of whether the bottom of the page is in the viewport or not.

HTML:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
          <p>&copy: 2018 First-name Last-name</p>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x "></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github-square fa-2x"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

An analogy to this is when you are using MS Excel and you "freeze" the top pane. No matter how much you scroll down the page, you will always see the frozen pane. I don't want this to happen but can't seem to find a way to do it.

Comment: `navbar-fixed-bottom` class in the first div inside the footer. That's the problem. Bootstrap classes are telling the footer to stay fixed to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Wow I don't know why but I thought `navbar-fixed-bottom` would just make the navbar stick to the bottom and not float up to the top of the page. if you put this comment as an answer I'll mark it as solved

Comment: Put as an answer! Good luck in your Bootstrap adventures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have `navbar-fixed-bottom` as a class on the first `div`. That's keeping it in a fixed position.